# Stretch inner content of vertical flexbox

Tags: html, css

is it possible to stretch the vertical content of inner flexboxes, without using height-properties?
The text at itempart three should be streched for available space
would like to prevent using js or fixed heights. Dont know if its possible with flexbox only.
Here is how it should look like?
[image]

```css
ul.itemlist {
  width: 80%;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
  display: grid;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none outside;
  clear: both;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
ul.itemlist li.item {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    
    list-style: none outside;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;

}
ul.itemlist li.item .itempart-wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
}
ul.itemlist li.item .itempart {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
ul.itemlist li.item .itempart:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
ul.itemlist li.item .itempart.one {
  text-align: center;
}
ul.itemlist li.item .itempart.two {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 600;
}
ul.itemlist li.item .itempart.three {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="itemlist">
  <li class="item">
    <div class="itempart-wrapper">
      <div class="itempart one"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></div>
      <div class="itempart two">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="itempart three">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et</div>
      <div class="itempart four"><a href="">More Details</a></div>
      </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="itempart-wrapper">
      <div class="itempart one"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></div>
      <div class="itempart two">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="itempart three">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.</div>
      <div class="itempart four"><a href="">More Details</a></div>        
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="itempart-wrapper">
      <div class="itempart one"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></div>
      <div class="itempart two">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="itempart three">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata</div>
      <div class="itempart four"><a href="">More Details</a></div>
    </div>
  </li><li class="item">
    <div class="itempart-wrapper">
      <div class="itempart one"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></div>
      <div class="itempart two">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="itempart three">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat</div>
      <div class="itempart four"><a href="">More Details</a></div>
    </div> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT:** added the forgotten itempart-wrapper

Comment: Change `.itempart {flex: 1}` to `.three {flex: 1}`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this helps but what i forgot at the code is that there is a wrapper inside of the li-element around the itemparts, is there a way for flexbox to ignore this or does this crash the solution?

Comment: Add the same flexbox properties to the wrapper, `display: flex` `flex-direction: column`, and `flex: 1`.

Comment: @sol you are my hero, that solved all my problems